# Beginner Python: help using while loop in function connected to list

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

This is the code I have come up with.

```
velocity =[40,60]
def tired(velocity, i = 0):
    while i >= 0:
        if velocity[i] > 50:
           velocity[i]= velocity [i]- velocity[i]* 0.9
        else:
            velocity[i]= velocity [i]+ velocity[i]* 0.25
    return velocity
print(tired(velocity))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is your question?

Comment: you can use for loop as well. 
`def tired(velocity):
    for i in range(len(velocity)):
        if velocity[i] > 50:
           velocity[i]= velocity [i]- velocity[i]* 0.9
        else:
            velocity[i]= velocity [i]+ velocity[i]* 0.25
    return velocity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vel = [40, 60]

def tired(v):
    i = 0
    new_vel = []
    while i < len(v):
        if v[i] >= 50:
            v[i] = v[i] - v[i]*0.9
        else:
            v[i] = v[i] + v[i]*0.25
        new_vel.append(v[i])
        i+= 1

    return new_vel

print(tired(vel))
```

**Output**

```
[50.0, 6.0]
```